# Get attributes value using javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-3

here is my code,

```
var selectedLabel = $(".alllabel li.active").attr("id");
```

I tried

```
    var selectedLabel = parent.document.getElementsByClassName(".alllabel li.active")
                       .getAttribute("id");
```

But undefined value gets. pls, help me out of here ..!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to do the equivalent operation to the jQuery code you showed using the DOM directly? If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method) is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

**If** your question is how to do the same thing as the jQuery code you showed using the DOM directly, the simplest way is:

```
var selectedLabel = document.querySelector(".alllabel li.active").id;
```

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) finds the first element in the DOM that matches a given CSS selector, and the `id` attribute has a *reflected property* called `id`.

Live Example:

```js
var selectedLabel = document.querySelector(".alllabel li.active").id;
console.log(selectedLabel);
```

```html
<ul class="alllabel">
    <li id="not-active">not-active</li>
    <li class="active" id="the-active-one">the active one</li>
</ul>
```

However, unlike the code using jQuery, that will throw an error if the element isn't found at all. If you want to get `undefined` (which is what jQuery would give you in that case), you'd do this:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".alllabel li.active");
var selectedLabel = element ? element.id : undefined;
```

Or with ES2021's *optional chaining* operator:

```
const selectedLabel = document.querySelector(".alllabel li.active")?.id;
```

That would give you `null` rather than `undefined` if not found, but...close enough. If you really, really wanted `undefined`, you could also use ES2021's nullish coalescing operator:

```
const selectedLabel = document.querySelector(".alllabel li.active")?.id ?? undefined;
```

---

If you wanted to get the value of an attribute that didn't have a reflected property, you'd use `getAttribute` as in your question. For instance, here's the first code block in this answer using `getAttribute` instead:

```
var selectedLabel = document.querySelector(".alllabel li.active").getAttribute("id");
```

But again, you don't need to do that with `id`.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName will return an array, while the getAttribute method should be executed on a single node. In your case, you can try:

```
parent.document.getElementsByClassName(".alllabel li.active")[0].getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: error like ...uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

Comment: example: https://jsbin.com/nuyayumihu/edit?html,console,output

Comment: please use attr instead of getAttribute.

Comment: @WaqarAkram - Why? the OP seems to want to replace their jQuery code with DOM code.